# I'm trying to get data from api and render it to the screen but I can render only last data not all api response

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fetch-api

App.tsx

```tsx
export interface Hotel {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  address1: string;
  address2: string;
  starRating: number;
  images: string[];
  longDescription: string;
}

export interface Room {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  longDescription: string;
}

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [hotels, setHotels] = useState<Hotel[]>([]);
  const [rooms, setRooms] = useState<Room[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getDetails = async () => {
      const hotel = await axios.get<Hotel[]>(`${uri}`);
      console.log(hotel.data);

      const response = hotel.data.map(async (i) => {
        const data = await (await fetch(`${uri}/${i.id}`)).json();
        return data;
      });
      Promise.all(response).then((fetchedData) => {
        const roomData = fetchedData.map((i) => {
          return i.rooms;
        });
        console.log(roomData);
        setRooms(roomData);
      });
    };
    getDetails();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <HotelCard hotels={hotels} rooms={rooms} />-
    </div>
  );
};
```

HotelCard.TSX is for only rendering hotel cards with rooms.

```tsx
interface HotelListProps {
  hotels: Hotel[];
  rooms: Room[];
}

const HotelCard: React.FC<HotelListProps> = ({ hotels, rooms }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {hotels.map((hotel) => (
        <div key={hotel.id}>
          <h1>{hotel.id}</h1>
          // more code
        </div>
      ))}
      {rooms.map((room) => (
        <div key={room.id}>
          <h1>{room.name}</h1>
          // more here...
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default HotelCard;
```

`console.log(roomData)` result is

> (4) [Array(8), Array(6), Array(9), Array(11)] 0: (8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] 1: (6)
> [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] 2: (9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},
> {…}, {…}, {…}] 3: (11) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},
> {…}, {…}] length: 4 [[Prototype]]: Array(0)

and when I tried to render rooms state and I got only last result not full.

Comment: You don't appear to be calling `setHotels()` anywhere. Also, I wouldn't recommend mixing Axios and fetch(), just for consistency's sake

Comment: make sure Room Ids are unique from the roomData since you have passed them as key.
Some times react behaves in an unnatural way becuase of this.

Comment: and it also seems like your room data is an Array of Arrays according tot the log you shared. So in that case in the Hotel car component, you would get an array as the item of the loop and not an object

Comment: This needs more debugging information. What **exactly** is the format of response from `uri` and `uri/:id`?

Comment: Response from uri is normal array [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] and uri/:id is array of array: [Array(8), Array(6), Array(9), Array(11)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things...

1. You aren't calling `setHotels` so your `hotels` state will never change
2. Assuming each *hotel* response has a `rooms` array, `roomData` will become an array of arrays and not the flat array your component expects

I'd also just stick with Axios (since you've already got it installed) instead of mixing in with `fetch()`

```ts
const { data: hotels } = await axios.get<Hotel[]>(uri);
const allRooms = await Promise.all(hotels.map(async ({ id }) => {
  // don't forget to provide a type for the response
  const { data: { rooms } } = await axios.get<{ rooms: Room[] }>(
    `${uri}/${encodeURIComponent(id)}`
  );

  return rooms;
}));

setHotels(hotels);
setRooms(allRooms.flat()); // flatten the array
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your log, roomData is an array of arrays.
You can modify your code snippet in Promise.all(...) to have roomData as array of objects:

```
let roomData = [];
fetchedData.forEach((i) => {
    roomData = [...roomData, ...i.rooms];
});
```